# In ChronicleQueue how to understand that the file read is complete or not, in side onRelease method

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have a chronicle reader (`ExcerptTailer`), Code follows,

```
 ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath).storeFileListener(new StoreFileListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReleased(int cycle, File file) {
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    file.delete();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).rollCycle(RollCycles.HOURLY).build();
ExcerptTailer excerptTailer = queueForReader.createTailer();
```

I implemented the `onRealease` method for deleting completed file.
But my problem is that the file got deleted on calling the `queue.close()`because of the code inside `onRelease` method.
In this case how can I understand that the file read isn't completed inside `onReleased` ?
Or is there a better way to implement my case?

Comment: queue.close() doesn't delete anything. Are you saying the space wasn't free up until the queue was closed?

Comment: Are you saying queue.close() doesn't call onRelease method? I think my question was not clear just updated. The file got deleted because of my onRelease implementation, I think.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean. We need to add a way to make it clear then a tailer no longer needs a cycle.

Comment: So, Is it an expected behavior ? (Calling onRelease on queue.close())